# Adding previously selected items from listbox for a total?

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing this program for a class; I have a `listbox` with values from 0-10 which are 'scores' which get recorded every time the user selects a new score (and clicks the button of course). I need to do the following;

1. an average of the scores, which I get through an accumulator and the counter
2. a number of scores, which I get through a counter
3. get the total scores (this is what's giving me trouble)

   here's the code I have for this so far :

   ```
   intScore = Convert.ToDecimal(lstScores.SelectedItem)

   'the counter and accumulator
   intTotal = intTotal + 1 
   decScoreAccumulator += intScore

   ' here's what calculates the average
   If intScore > 0 Then
       decScorAvg = decScoreAccumulator / intTotal
   End If
   ```

   Here's an image of it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aomQO.png

The number and average I can get to work, since its just using the accumulator and the counter. But no matter what I do, I can't add the values selected for the total. So does anyone know how I can get it to give me total of all the selected scores?

Comment: Isn't `decScoreAccumulator` just your total?

Comment: wow,i'm an idiot...i had not realized that,well I guess it is...thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Sure! Don't worry about missing that...I miss things like that too when I program. :)

Comment: So i'm not alone then? haha
honestly i'm such a noob at this.But seriously, thanks! i was about give up on it.

Comment: haha, nope, you're not alone at all. (I've seen people have code that adds zero to something, like `x = x + 0`...lol) Good luck!

Comment: haha guess not,and please do! it might be useful to others,since i'm not the only noob who might do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code looks good, and you look like your doing everything correctly. You even already have the total in your current code:

```
decScoreAccumulator += intScore
```

Because you're adding the score each time to `decScoreAccumulator`, this variable has the total you're looking for (assuming it's not confined to the scope of the button click). HTH. Good luck!